# My bootloader can't be compiled with gcc 4.6 and 4.7 ... only 4.5

Tags: linux, gcc, bootloader

I created my bootloader before 2 years under debian squeeze/stable with `gcc` 4.5. Now in debian wheezy/sid can't be compiled with 4.6 and 4.7 because creates bigger sections from these i expecting to produce the final binary by hand. This is not problem for me now since in debian wheezy/sid the `gcc` 4.5 is still there but i 'd like to make it possible to be compiled with `gcc` 4.6 and 4.7.

I produce the final binary like this:

the source files are compiled with:

```
gcc-4.5 -Wall -O3 -c -m32 -I. -o assemblybin-objects/vga_pm.S.o vga_pm.S
```

linked with:

```
ld -nostdlib -T binary.ld assemblybin-objects/vga_pm.S.o ... and other objects here ... -o bootloader.bin
```

the contents of the `binary.ld` is:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary","binary","binary")
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386)

SECTIONS
{
. = 0;
.bootloader : {
    . = 0x600;
    *(.bootstrap);
    . = 0x7fa;
    BYTE(0x11);
    BYTE(0x33);
    BYTE(0x55);
    BYTE(0x77);
    BYTE(0x55);
    BYTE(0xaa);
    _bootstrap_end = .;
    . = 0x800;
    *(.sysinit);
    _sysinit_end = .;
    . = 0x1000;
    *(.pages);
    _pages_end = .;
    . = 0x5000;
    *(.sysconf);
    *(.presystem);
    *(.system);
    *(.library);
    *(.text);
    *(.data);
    *(.bss);
    *(.rodata);
    *(.rodata.*);
    . = 0xeffc;
    BYTE(0x11);
    BYTE(0x33);
    BYTE(0x55);
    BYTE(0x77);
    _system_end = .;
}

. = ASSERT(_bootstrap_end <= 0x800,"Bootstrap section big!");
. = ASSERT(_sysinit_end <= 0x1000,"Sysinit section big!");
. = ASSERT(_pages_end <= 0x5000,"Pages section big!");
. = ASSERT(_system_end <= 0xf000,"System initialization section big!");
}
```

at last creating the final binary with `dd`.

I saw that when compiled with `gcc` 4.6 and 4.7 the linker adds some bytes (250-300) at the begin of the `bootloader.bin`.

I'm using the `ld` from `binutils` 2.22 and cook with my own recipes for the build process.

My actual questions are:

**What are the differences between these versions of the `gcc` compiler and they produce bigger sections or instructing the linker through the elf object files to add these bytes at the begin of the `bootloader.bin` file?**

**Is there any command line argument for `gcc` 4.6 and/or 4.7 which will turn off a feature that may produce bigger sections than the `gcc` 4.5 or to remove the instructions those saying the linker to add these bytes at the begin of the `bootloader.bin` file?**

edit 17-08-2012: I'm lil busy these days but soon i 'll update with the results of tests i did.

Answer to @strnk and @Dan Aloni: when i saw this problem the first i did is to exclude useless sections but the results are the same ... i think because the `bootloader.bin` is a simple binary with the linked code of the needed sections at the right position as the linker instructed to do, without section names, relocation and debug informations and symbols ... `bootloader.bin` file is not an elf object file.

Please consider the changes of the actual questions.
Thanks for everything ... i 'll be back soon

edit 31-08-2012: Okay guys thanks for your help. The answer given by @Dan Aloni and accomplished with `ldscript` as @strnk shows

```
/DISCARD/ : {
    *(.eh_frame)
    *(.eh_frame_hdr)
}
```

after the asserts.

Comment: output would be useful, maybe you can post elf files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By compiling a trivial C file with the flags you provided, between `gcc-4.5` and `gcc-4.6`, and using `objdump -h` to examine the output, it seems that the `.eh_frame` section is introduced in `gcc-4.6`.

The `ld` script you provided does not take care of that section, and it probably should. You can use `strip -R .eh_frame -R .eh_frame_hdr` to remove that section and others from the object files prior to linking.

Anyway, since the linker is the same for both gcc versions, `objdump -h` on the object files will hint at the difference that causes this problem.

Comment: would like to direct you to @strnk's [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11984547/922168) to potentially alleviate this problem, good diagnosis though, +1

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any command line argument which will turn off a feature that may produce bigger sections

Yes: if you care about size, you should build with `-Os`. The `-O3` explicitly enables optimizations which could lead to larger code size. Since the bootloader executes *once*, using `-O3` for it is almost certainly wrong.

Edit:

> "Optimization in assembly is meaningless ...
>   ...  and other objects here ..."

Is *all* of your code in assembly? If so, optimization level is indeed meaningless, but then you should be able to simply compare output from `readelf -S vga_pm.S.o` built with both compilers, and see exactly *which* sections are different.

But it appears more likely that some of your objects are *not* in assembly, in which case the difference between `-O3` and `-Os` will be quite meaningful.

Comment: With "Is there any command line argument which will turn off a feature that may produce bigger sections?" i mean a possible feature added to gcc versions 4.6 and 4.7 that makes bigger sections than the version 4.5.

Comment: The optimization in assembly is meaningless. I'm just doing it to see if there any difference with my code and the optimized results ... i didn't notice any change.

Comment: First of all thanks for your time. The problem is not there because i don't have problem with the size of the code but with the size of the sections. The code doesn't excides the desired size of the sections but the gcc 4.6 and 4.7 creates bigger sections and i can't find the reason

Comment: @memosdp, don't you have `.note.gnu.build-id` section in your binary?

Comment: this is my haunch as well, sometimes the optimizer does things that shouldn't be done and the newer versions of gcc could have changed this http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html

Comment: @Yasushi Shoji No i don't have this section in bootloader.bin.

Answer (score 3):

GCC adds some unwanted debug sections to its binary output (use `objdump -h <file>` to see them), I usually put those I don't want in a `/DISCARD/` rule in my ld scripts to get rid of them :

```
/DISCARD/ : {
        *(.debug_*)
        *(.note*)
        *(.indent)
        *(.comment)
        *(.stab)
        *(.stabstr)
        *(.eh_frame)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to note that *you are not actually* using *GCC at all*.

vga_pm.S, judging from the file extension, is assembler source containing preprocessor directives, so you need the `cpp` preprocessor to turn that into preprocessed (.s) source. Note that the GNU assembler (`as`) has all the necessary native directives, e.g. for file inclusion, to make this step unnecessary.

"Compiling" .s source to .o object file doesn't require GCC either, as this can be done just as well using `as` directly (which is part of the binutils package).

Then you use `ld` for linking the object file into a binary. Again, `ld` is part of the binutils package.

Using GCC as a frontend *confuses* the issue, has little to no benefit, and might actually be at the root of your problem. Point in case, you told us which GCC versions you used, but you didn't tell us which *binutils* versions you used...

I recommend not depending on tools that are not strictly necessary, to keep your build process as simple as possible. In this case, drop GCC from your bootloader build step.

Comment: I think it can't be more simple. I'm using gcc,ld,cook(with my recipes) and dd.

Comment: i forgot to say about binutils version ... is 2.22

Comment: @memosdp: As I said, if your source is assembly, call the assembler directly instead of using the GCC frontend.